# Height 100% when parent height is auto

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For example, I have following html:

```
<html><head>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style type="text/css">
            .col-1{
                height: 300px;
            }
            .col-2{
                /*
                height: 100% not working, how to stretch col-2 like col-1
                */
            }
         </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-2">
            </div>
        </div>

</body></html>
```

Height of container is auto, but actual height is defined, because col-1 height is 300px. How to set col-2 height 100% of actual parent height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try to use "row row-eq-height" classes.

Try to use `<div class="row row-eq-height"></div>` instead of `<div class="row"></div>`

And add this CSS property to your custom CSS

```
.row-eq-height{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `.row` outside of any `col-*` because `col-*` have float attribute. To make the same height of `col-*`, add `.row-eq-height` with this style:

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

The HTML is like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-1">
      a
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-2">
      b
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/n1uouL6x/)

Answer (score 1):

min-height:100% usually works.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.container {position:relative;height:600px;width:100%;background-color:black;}
.col-1{float:left;width:50%;height:300px;background-color:red}
.col-2{float:left;min-height:100%;width:40%;background-color:green}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-2"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/001cbskq/

You are using bootstrap but I am not in this example.

Comment: I do't want to set height of container. It defined by col-1 height.

Comment: You can only use the height of a parent to make a child 100% height of it. A child can only talk to another child by the assistance of JS. Where the javascript reads .col-1's height then tells col-2 to repeat that height.